# How to store multiple permissions in a table from values of checkboxes?

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm a building a simple system to allow/disallow permissions in specific areas but I want to know what is the best way to send the values of checkboxes from `jquery.ajax()` to process in a PHP function and insert in a table:

Doesn't exists a problem, just I want know a way to Insert the value of each checkbox from each Area in a table `table_perfiles_permisos` without create a variable for each checkbox and insert! Some dynamic using foreach or something.

[image: checkboxes permissions]

**HTML**

```
    <form> 
    <div id="permisosPerfiles">
        <div id="leftPermisos">
        <p>
        <h4>Usuarios</h4>
        <label for="pCrearUsuario">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearUsuario" name="permUsuarios[]" value="CrearU" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="pBuscarUsuario">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarUsuario" name="permUsuarios[]" value="BuscarU" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarUsuario">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarUsuario" name="permUsuarios[]" value="ModificarU" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarUsuario">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarUsuario" name="permUsuarios[]" value="EliminarU" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>

        <p>
        <h4>Clientes</h4>
        <label for="pCrearCliente">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearCliente" name="permClientes[]" value="CrearC" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarCliente">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarCliente" name="permClientes[]" value="BuscarC" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarCliente">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarCliente" name="permClientes[]" value="ModificarC" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarCliente">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarCliente" name="permClientes[]" value="EliminarC" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h4>Marca, Producto Subproducto</h4>
        <label for="pCrearMPS">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearMPS" name="permMPS[]" value="CrearMPS" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarMPS">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarMPS" name="permMPS[]" value="BuscarMPS" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarMPS">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarMPS" name="permMPS[]" value="ModificarMPS" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarMPS">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarMPS" name="permMPS[]" value="EliminarMPS" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
        </div>

        <div id="rightPermisos">
        <p>
        <h4>Póliza</h4>
        <label for="pCrearPoliza">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearPoliza" name="permPoliza[]" value="CrearP" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarPoliza">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarPoliza" name="permPoliza[]" value="BuscarP" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarPoliza">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarPoliza" name="permPoliza[]" value="ModificarP" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarPoliza">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarPoliza" name="permPoliza[]" value="EliminarP" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <h4>Servicio</h4>
        <label for="pCrearServicio">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearServicio" name="permServicio[]" value="CrearS" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarServicio">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarServicio" name="permServicio[]" value="BuscarS" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarServicio">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarServicio" name="permServicio[]" value="ModificarS" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarServicio">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarServicio" name="permServicio[]" value="EliminarS" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery** to serialize form

formchecks = $(form).serialize();

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: formchecks,
        success: function(response) {

             if (response == "success") {
                 //actions if success    
             } else {
                //actions if doesn't success   
             }
        }
});
```

**So should be the data stored**

```
table_perfiles
*id   *nombre   *descripcion
1      NameOne    DescOne
2      NameTwo    DescTwo

table_perfiles_permisos
*id_perfil *area_permiso *buscar *crear *eliminar *modificar 
    1            1          0      1         1        1
    1            2          0      0         1        0
    2            1          1      1         1        1


table_areas_permisos
*id *nombre
1    usuarios
2    clientes
3    mps
4    poliza
5    servicio
```

e.g. if checkbox is checked, will store 1 else will be 0 for each checkbox in each area

I hope I have explained enough.

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem? Looks like you've already got this sorted, what exactly isn't working?

Comment: Doesn't exists a problem, just I want know a way to Insert the value of each checkbox from each Area in a table table_perfiles_permisos without create a variable for each checbox and insert! Some dinamyc using foreach or something!

Comment: Oh right I see what you mean. Well I would create 1 large 2d array in the HTML form so you just have to iterate 1 variable which you could dynamically alter. So you can change it to something like `<input id="pCrearUsuario" name="perm[Usuarios][]" value="CrearU" type="checkbox" />` then all you have to do is loop `$_POST['perm']`, and then you can loop each sub item to get the permissions for each area. I'm not sure I explained that very well...

Comment: I think it will work, did not know who could do this: name = "perm [Users] []", but when I use this name in jquery, how would it be? that is usually $ ('form input[name = user]:checked') ....

Comment: That's an interesting point. Probably the best thing to do would be to give all your inputs a specific class and use that to select then in jQ instead: `$('form input.myClassName:checked')` - but I admit it does make that element of it more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than storing each permission type in a separate database column, you can make it a binary number and store entire permission sets as integers. This way you can always add new permission types without having to modify your DB.

For instance, if you define permission type constants as follows:

```
define('PERMISSION_CREATE', bindec('0001'));
define('PERMISSION_SEARCH', bindec('0010'));
define('PERMISSION_EDIT',   bindec('0100'));
define('PERMISSION_DELETE', bindec('1000'));
```

you can then combine them with bitwise OR operator:

```
$permissions_set = (PERMISSION_CREATE | PERMISSION_SEARCH);
```

this equals 0011 (binary) or 3, which is the number you can store in your DB.

To check if a specific permission is "on", use bitwise AND:

```
if( ($permissions_set & PERMISSION_CREATE) === true ) {
    // create is on
}
```

Comment: It's a good way to set permissions but, I'm use php sessions, then when the user login, their permits will be loaded depending on area where you are, be allowed or denied access on the permission set... then, ur example works for this?